# Is it possible to initialize new position of vector using array without push_back (C++ STL)

Tags: c++, stl

While I was doing experiment with vector in C++, I was facing some strange problem. May be it was because of my little knowledge of C++ STL. I am using Code::Blocks 16.01 IDE having GNU GCC compiler in it.

**When I run this code:**

```
vector <int> vec;

vec.push_back(66);
vec.push_back(12);

cout << vec[1] << endl;
```

> The output is obviously correct i.e. `12`.

**Again, when I run this code:**

```
vector <int> vec;

vec.push_back(66);
vec.push_back(12);

vec[1] = 18;

cout << vec[1] << endl;
```

> This time the output is also correct i.e. `18`.

**This time I did `push_back()` for only first 2 elements of vector. But initialized the value of 6th element using array and after running the following code:**

```
vector <int> vec;

vec.push_back(66);
vec.push_back(12);

vec[5] = 18;

cout << vec[5] << endl;
```

> The output is again fine i.e. `18`.

**But, when I run the code below, the console window crashes immediately. I don't know why.**

```
vector <int> vec;

vec.push_back(66);
vec.push_back(12);

cout << vec[1] << endl;

vec[5] = 18;

cout << vec[5] << endl;
```

Once I used `cout` once, the program crashes. Why this is happening? Am I missing something about the connection of vector with array? I want to know the proper way to handle vector using array or is it bad practice to use array to handle vector?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at **Unlike std::map::operator[], this operator never inserts a new element into the container.**

Comment: You can resize() your vector - which will add new entries to your vector initializing them with default or provided values.

Comment: You are not using an array. An array is a specific data structure and might refer to a C-style array (`SomeType a[size]`) or an `std::array`. What you're using is `operator[]`.

Comment: vector's `operator[]` gives undefined behaviour if used to access a non-existent element.    Accessing `vec[5]` for a vector with two elements is such a case - a crash is one possible symptom of that.

Comment: @RakibulIslam - undefined behaviour means the C++ standard does not describe any constraint on what happens.   Seeming to behave correctly is one possible outcome.   Behaving correctly one time, and then incorrectly the next is another.  Always crashing is yet another.

Comment: Trivial answer to title question: yes, of course. You can use `emplace_back` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something about the connection of vector with array?

No you do not. If you misbehave the same way with array you will have the same issue:

```
int array[2];
array[5] = 18; // this is undefined behaviour
std::cout << array[5] << std::endl; // this is undefined behaviour as well
```

you can even see desired output in some environment, but it could crash on another, or start to crash when you change your code. That is problem with UB - it is unpredictable. And accessing elements out of range has similar consequences with array and `std::vector`, difference - you can resize `std::vector` but cannot do that to array.

Answer (score 1):

When you access an element of a `std::vector` that is outside of the size of the vector, you get undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means what it sounds like - anything could happen. This is why sometimes your program will crash, and other times it works fine. You should not rely on undefined behavior for anything, instead you should resize your vector using `std::vector::resize` before inserting something outside of the size of the vector.

Comment: The `push_back()` function can increase the vector by n elements, this depends on the allocator logic.

Comment: You can determine the size of the vector with `std::vector::size()`.

Also, if you want to create a vector with a certain size, you can pass an integer into the contructor, e.g. `std::vector<int> x(10);`

Comment: @mshindal you can do this with the capacity method http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity

Comment: A vector has a member named `size()`.   Guess what property of the vector it returns.   RTFM.

Comment: @Raynigon - A vector's capacity is not the same as the number of elements.

Comment: @Peter but then you only the the amount of elements stored in the vector, not the real size of memory which is allocated.

Comment: @Peter Then how the size of vector differs with the number of elements.

Comment: @RakibulIslam the vector allocates memory for n elements, the size gives you only the amount of elements stored in a vector.

For exmaple you can have a vector with 4 Elements stored in it, but std::vector will reserve more memory so it wont have to reallocate memory on the next push_back.

Comment: @Raynigon - that's true, but also has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @Peter This was meant to be a little explanation why the code still worked, in some cases. Not an advice to assign elements in the resevered memory of an std::vector. Any idea how to better point this out ?

Comment: @Raynignon - when behaviour is undefined, there is no point in explaining why it works in some cases, unless you have deep knowledge about the specific compiler being used.   The nature of undefined behaviour is that any resultant behaviour can happen.